# Server Reboot: How to analyze the root cause

Tags: server, 20.04, shutdown, crash, reboot

We have an incident of a sudden reboot of our production ubuntu server 20.04. How to know what triggered the reboot and was it normal or abrupt? We do not have auditd installed. And the /var/log/syslog shows only clue that "[systemd] received: SIGINT" before shutdown.

Please advise

Comment: Readers: see the same question on [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2476782).

Comment: please edit to say this is a VM. VERY important info.

Answer (score 2):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, or an intentional reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Overheating is most likely caused by dust. Power down your system. Unblock your fans and vents, clean out the dust. Ensure air circulation. Dust that coats heat exchangers and chips is a good insulator,  and bad for cooling. Don't disassemble your computer until you have downloaded the manufacturer's  manual, and researched how-to-clean. Make this information available for when your computer isn't (paper, other computer) **Don't use water.**

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Comment: I see the below output from the above suggested command:
Unmounted Mount unit for lxd, revision 23243.
swap.img.swap: Succeeded.
Deactivated swap /swap.img.
shared.mount: Succeeded.
Unmounted /shared.
 multipathd[864]: --------shut down-------
systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
Stopped Create System Users.
systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Stopped Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller.
Reached target Shutdown.
Reached target Final Step.
systemd-reboot.service: Succeeded
Finished Reboot
Reached target Reboot Shutting down

Comment: What does the above output signify? Is it a normal shutdown or an abrupt shutdown?

Comment: @AbdullahMadani the above information is not enough to know anything, since it only describes the shutdown process. What you need to look for is the line(s) directly before whenever things started shutting down.

Comment: @waltinator OP only mentioned this in the Ubuntu Forums post, but apparently this is a VM that shut down, and all other VMs running on the same machine are fine.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].